# How to find the equation of a rotated ellipse?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose $$x^2-xy+y^2-3x=0.$$

How do I find the equation of this ellipse so I can draw it?

Comment: What you have written down is the equation. You want to know the parametrisation I guess?

Comment: What does “Suppose $x^2-xy+y^2-3x$” mean?

Comment: @Ernie060 Hard to be an equation without any equality mentioned!

Comment: What you have isn't an equation. An equation needs $=$ in it somewhere. However, if you just add $=0$ at the end, you will have an equation, and that will be the equation of some ellipse. I suspect that that is what you meant.

Comment: @rschwieb I know that strictly speaking it isn't an equation, but I tacitly assumed that there had to be "equal to zero" right after it. Anyway, I wanted to know whether the OP wants a parametrisation. But that's still not clear...

Comment: Merely to _draw_ the ellipse, you can find the minimum and maximum possible values of $x$ and $y$ and plot the points at each minimum and maximum. Then you can either connect the dots immediately with free-hand curves or plot more points (as many as you like) to guide the curves. The center of the ellipse is also easy to find this way, but the orientation of the axes of the ellipse is not so easy to find this way (although in this case you get lucky and I think it should be fairly obvious).

Comment: @Ernie060 petty sure the user wants a strategy to draw the ellipse as if it were in a “standard form”, but that this one is not rectilinear to the axes.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, indeed, that I see know. But the question was, some hours ago, not clear to me. And when one says "drawing", the first thing that pops in my mind is "parametrisation". But I know it is not necessary to find a parametrisation in order to draw a curve. Especially for an ellipse, that would be overkill...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation of ellipse in a general form is:

$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

with an additional condition that:

$$4AC - B^2 > 0$$

Such ellipse has axes rotated with respect to $x,y$ axis and the angle of rotation is:

$$\tan (2\alpha)={B \over A-C}$$

In your particular case $A=C$ so:

$$\tan(2\alpha)=\infty\implies 2\alpha=90^\circ\implies\alpha=45^\circ$$

So your ellipse has axes rotated for $45^\circ$ with respect to $x,y$ axes. Rotate the coordiante system $xOy$ around point $O$ for $45^\circ$. Rotated axes ($x',y'$) will be parallel with axes of the ellipse. If you have a point with coordinates $(x,y)$ in the system $xOy$ and the same point with coordinates $(x',y')$ in the rotated system $x'Oy'$, the connection between them is:

$$x = x' \cos{\alpha} - y'\sin{\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(x'-y')\tag{1}$$

$$y = x' \sin{\alpha} + y'\cos{\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(x'+y')\tag{2}$$

Replace (1) and (2) into your equation of ellipse and, after a few simplifications, you will get:

$$\frac{x'^2}{3}+y'^2-x'\sqrt2+y'\sqrt2=0$$

This equation can be written in the following form:

$$\frac{(x'-\frac32\sqrt2)^2}{(\sqrt3)^2}+(y'+\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2=2$$

$$\frac{(x'-\frac32\sqrt2)^2}{(\sqrt6)^2}+\frac{(y'+\frac{\sqrt2}{2})^2}{(\sqrt2)^2}=1$$

So in the rotated coordinate system $x'Oy'$ this ellipse has center in point $(\frac{3\sqrt2}{2},-\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$, with semi-axes equal to $\sqrt6$ and $\sqrt2$.

And also notice that your ellipse passes through the origin $O(0,0)$. If you draw carefully the ellipse should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, the fact that $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2-xy+y^2-3x=0\}$ is an ellipse follows from the fact that the discriminant of $x^2-xy+y^2$ is negative. Such ellipse goes through $(0;0),(3;0),(3;3),(1;2),(1;-1),(4;2)$, the $y$-axis is the tangent at the origin and the line $y=-1$ is the tangent at $(1;-1)$. These informations are more than enough to draw the ellipse and find its center and vertices:

[image]

I am just exploiting that

1. Any ellipse is the image of a circle with respect to an invertible linear map, hence
2. If we have parallel chords, the line through their midpoints goes through the center.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\pmatrix{P&q\\ q^T&r}$ be the matrix representation of a quadratic form, where $P$ is symmetric and non-singular, $q$ is a vector and $r$ is a scalar. Then there exists an orthogonal diagonalisation $P=QDQ^T$. It is easy to verify that
$$
\pmatrix{v^T&1}\pmatrix{P&q\\ q^T&r}\pmatrix{v\\ 1}\equiv
\pmatrix{(v+P^{-1}q)^TQ&1}\pmatrix{D&0\\ 0&r-q^TP^{-1}q}\pmatrix{Q^T(v+P^{-1}q)\\ 1}.
$$
(You shouldn't find this identity surprising if you are familiar with [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) and [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).) It follows that if $L$ is the locus of a point $v$ given by the equation $\pmatrix{v^T&1}A\pmatrix{v\\ 1}=0$, then $L=QL'-P^{-1}q$, where $L'$ is the locus of a point $u$ given by the equation $u^TDu = q^TP^{-1}q-r$.

---

In your case,
\begin{aligned}
A&=\pmatrix{
 1  &-1/2&-3/2\\
-1/2& 1  & 0\\
-3/2& 0  & 0},\\
P&=\pmatrix{
 1  &-1/2\\
-1/2& 1}
=QDQ^T:=
\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}}
\pmatrix{\frac12\\ &\frac32}
\pmatrix{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\\ -\frac1{\sqrt{2}}&\frac1{\sqrt{2}}},\\
q&=\pmatrix{-3/2\\ 0},\ r=0,\\
P^{-1}q&=-\pmatrix{2\\ 1},\ q^TP^{-1}q-r=3.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, the locus of $u=(x,y)^T$ is the ellipse $L':\frac12x^2+\frac32y^2=3$ and the locus $L$ of $v=Qu-P^{-1}q$ is obtained by an anticlockwise rotation of $L'$ by $\frac\pi4$ radian followed by a translation of the centre of the ellipse to $(2,1)$.